# Sharing variable scope with jsdom and jquery in Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

So, I was writing a simple page scraper with jsdom and jquery, and ran across an issue I'm not sure how to solve.

Here's some code that works (changed the URL):

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var fs = require('fs');
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("./js/jquery-min.js").toString();

//There's two pages of product, here's page 1
jsdom.env({
        url: 'http://exampleshoppingpage.com',
        src: [ jquery ],
        done: function(error, window){
                var $ = window.$;
                $('.productlist .product .title a').each(function() {
                        console.log($(this).text());
                });
        } 
});

//And do the exact same thing for page 2
jsdom.env({
        url: 'http://exampleshoppingpage.com?page=2',
        src: [ jquery ],
        done: function(error, window){
                var $ = window.$;
                $('.productlist .product .title a').each(function() {
                        console.log($(this).text());
                });
        } 
});
```

But what I would really like to do is get all of these products and sort them before printing them out.  Here's what I attempted:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var fs = require('fs');
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("./js/jquery-min.js").toString();
var products = [];


//There's two pages of product, here's page 1
jsdom.env({
        url: 'http://exampleshoppingpage.com',
        src: [ jquery ],
        done: function(error, window){
                var $ = window.$;
                products $('.productlist .product .title a').each(function() {
                        products.push($(this).text());
                });
        } 
});

//And do the exact same thing for page 2
jsdom.env({
        url: 'http://exampleshoppingpage.com?page=2',
        src: [ jquery ],
        done: function(error, window){
                var $ = window.$;
                $('.productlist .product .title a').each(function() {
                        products.push($(this).text());
                });
        } 
});

products = products.sort();
console.log (products.join("\n"));
```

I get an empty array.  I've attempted a few other ways to determine if I was just doing something stupid.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the jQuery in the jsdom not sharing scope with the outer part of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a case where we have to remember to think asynchronously. Your scope is fine, but you are trying to dump `products` to console before it's populated with data.

Also, `Array.prototype.sort()` [operates on the array directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). It does not return an array.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var jquery = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js";

var products = [];

//  page 1
jsdom.env({
        url: 'http://news.ycombinator.com/',
        scripts: [ jquery ],
        done: function(error, window){
                var $ = window.$;
                $('td.title:not(:last) a').each(function() {
                        products.push( $(this).text() );
                });
                //      page 2
                jsdom.env({
                        url: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=2',
                        scripts: [ jquery ],
                        done: function(error, window){
                                var $ = window.$;
                                $('td.title:not(:last) a').each(function() {
                                        products.push( $(this).text() );

                                });
                                products.sort();
                                console.log( products );
                        }
                });
        }
});
```

Comment: this is also a good example of how [crazy and unreadable](http://callbackhell.com/) javascript can get, and how [Promises will make life awesome](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), IMHO.

Comment: Gah!  Asynchronous thinking gets me every time!  Especially when I'm switching back and forth from traditional programming.

Comment: i KNOW! i can't wait until it's just all javascript, all the time